# IDA Pro: What does "Create EXE file..." option do?

Tags: disassembly, ida, patching

I have come across `File -> Create EXE file...` option in IDA. I thought one couldn't use IDA for patching. I have tried playing with it. However, it gives me the following error: **`This type of output files is not supported.`**

What is this option for? What is possible usage of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This option has limited value.

---

> IDA produces executable files only for:
>
> - MS DOS .exe
> - MS DOS .com
> - MS DOS .drv
> - MS DOS .sys
> - general binary
> - Intel Hex Object Format
> - MOS Technology Hex Object Format
>
> -- *IDA Help file*

---

> While this is the most promising menu option, it unfortunately is also the most crippled. In a nutshell, it doesn't work for most file types...
>
> -- *[The IDA Pro Book](http://nostarch.com/idapro.htm), Chapter 14*

That chapter goes into more detail why this option is not very useful. For starters, IDA doesn't parse and save contents of sections such as `.rsrc`, and doesn't have a way to rebuild import/export tables back into their original format.

Read this book. Not just for this question, it's a good and useful read.

Comment: Got the book. It's great read. Thanks for the pointer.